# What should I do when SetEvent return false

Tags: multithreading, winapi, events, synchronization

I am writing a little program,the program execute 4 threads which will execute funcA(),I use for event objects and WaitForMultipleObject() to make the main thread block until  4 threads is over their task,it is easy to kown I will use setEvent() in funA(),I am wonder what should I do if SetEvent() is execute failed,the main will always block?Is thier any way to avoid this?

P.S:I only know SetEvent will failed when the HANDLE is invalid,is their any more reason for its failed?

Comment: Please provide more context/example. Also, what is the value of GetLastError() directly after the failure?

Comment: @NuSkooler The code is simple and thier is no wrong with my code,I just want to make my code robust, so I use `if(false == SetEvent(myHandle))` every where, when the condition is   true,myHandle is not set signaled, so I just simple return false,but I think this is not so robust,because my main thread will waiting myHandle forever,should I use CloseHandle(myHandle) to avoid this?

Comment: SetEvent() failing is an *extremely* nasty mishap.  It is so bad that you either completely ignore the possibility of failure because your program state is so corrupted that a diagnostic just gives false leads.  Or you immediately terminate your program so no further harm can be done.

Comment: If you run into an unexpected program state there is nothing you can reasonably do about it. Either terminate the program immediately (when using C) or throw an exception without catching it and let the `unexpected()`-handler perform its duty. As an aside, `SetEvent` returns a `BOOL`. You should compare it against `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: If you're using C, you can use RaiseException to throw a Windows exception.

Comment: WaitForMultipleObjects() will fire with WAIT_ABANDONED_0 if a handle is closed. If you're suggesting CloseHandle() on the handle that SetEvent() failed on, it *may* give you desired results. Then again, as I asked before: Why did it fail in the first place? There aren't many reasons for it to fail other than bad/invalid handles or perhaps lack of rights (e.g. EVENT_MODIFY_STATE).

Comment: @NuSkooler Frankly,I only meet failed when the handle is a invalid handle,I don`t know is there any other reasons:(，thank u for your answer,thanks

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for your tip, I use true and false just because it is my company convention,So I have no choice here.Thanks for you advice:)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can throw a C++ exception to intentionally crash the process.

In C you can crash the process nicely using the Windows API function [RaiseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to raise a Windows structured exception.